# How to pull out part of a string after a regex value

Tags: regex, string, split, delimiter

Trying to pull part of a string after a variable regex value to be written to a csv

I have a script that scrubs reports for important information.  the way the report is written it has MGRS grids followed by a number.  for ex. the report will have several lines that look like this: (MGRS: 12ABC12345678//, 23 words followed by more words MGRS: 98ZYX87654321// 17 even more words).  I am trying to create a csv that just has the MGRS grid and the following number.

```
    MGRS_Regex= re.compile('\d{1,2}[A-Za-z]\s?[A-Z-a-z]{2}\s?\d{2,5}\s?{2,5}')
    grid_list = []

    for f in file_list:
        with open(f,'r')as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csvDictReader(csv_file)
            for row in csv_reader:
                for key, value in row.items():
                    if key == 'text_field':  ##text_field is the record##
                        grid_pull = MGRS_Regex.findall(value)
                        for grid in grid_pull:
                            grid_list.append(grid)
                for grid in grid_list:
                    if field == 'important number':  ## field is the key the new csv file##
                        text = row.get('text_field')
                        grid_search = text.find(grid)
                        important_number = text[grid_search : 3]
                        important_info.update({field:important_number})
```

expecting to get a dictionaries with the varible field"name" as the key and the sliced out str as the value

Comment: Why do we have to learn about somebody's phd project, can't you simplify this ? At least when asking a question . The question is that little part that needs a solution that you cannot do.

Comment: I'm not sure what flavor of regex you are using but if you want to capture various parts of the regex you should use a capture group. If you tell me what language you are using and give me a sample of what the input looks like I can probably help you build a regex for that.

Comment: unfourtantly I can't add a real sample of the text because it is proriotory information.  best way I can describe it is; I have several hundred reports that have information regarding locations and how long some one was there.  so textualy it looks like ( blah blah blah blah blah MGRS:12ABC12345678// 13 weeks blah blah blah blah MGRS: 98ZYX87654321// 9 days blah blah blah)

Comment: I can pull out the (MGRS) using the provided regex code easy enough but I am having trouble slicing out the "13 weeks" part to do temporal analysis on the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'll offer up this regex in hope's it will be sufficient

`(?i)\d{1,2}[a-z]\s*[a-z]{2}\s*\d{2,5}\s*\d{2,5}//\s*\d+(?:\s*(?:years|days|weeks))?`

https://regex101.com/r/Dwoz3a/1

Expanded

```
 (?i)
 \d{1,2} [a-z] \s* [a-z]{2} \s* \d{2,5} \s* \d{2,5} 
 // \s* \d+ 
 (?:
      \s* 
      (?: years | days | weeks )
 )?
```